# Calculate the number of terms in geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given are the following geometric sequences:
13, 23.4, ...

The common ratio is 1.8, so far so good.

But how can I calculate the number of terms which are smaller then 9.6E13?

The solution says 51. I have no clue.

I'm looking for a hint to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you figure out how big the $n$th term is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$13\cdot (1.8)^{n-1}\geq 9.6\times 10^{13}\Longrightarrow 1.8^{n-1}\geq 0.738461\times 10^{13}=:\alpha\Longrightarrow n-1\geq\frac{\log\alpha}{\log 1.8}=....$$

Comment: Thanks...I got the solutions steps. Actually, it's other way with the sign. It should be smaller then 9.6E13. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I know you want to know the number of elements smaller than the given number, but knowing *the first* element bigger than it, which is the 52th, you automatically know that there are 51 elements *less* than that...so the sign is correct if one knows how to interpret it.

Answer (score 2):

Write it as $a_{n}=13\cdot 1.8^{n}$, $n\ge 0$. Then solve the inequality $a_{n}\ge 9.6E13$. That will tell you the first $n$ for which the terms arent smaller than 9.6E13, and it should be simple to find the answer from there

Comment: I think you meant $\,a_n=13\cdot (1.8)^{n-1}\,$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I think you're right about that.

Comment: @Peter In my opinion it leads to an logarithmic calculation then, right?

Comment: Indeed it does, @swisshenry